# Spring MethodArgumentNotValidException fields are all time null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an entity with some constraint :

```
@FieldMustBeEqualToAnotherField(
        field = "sentCharges.currency",
        fieldToCompare = "settlementAmount.currency",
        message = "Sent charges currency must be null or equal to settlement amount currency")
public class MT103ApiDTO {
....
}
```

One exception handler :

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {


    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        List<Feedback> feedbacks = new LinkedList<>();
        ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors().forEach(fields -> {
            feedbacks.add(new Feedback().setCode(INVALID_FORMAT)
                                        .setLabel(fields.getDefaultMessage())
                                        .setSeverity(ERROR)
                                        .setType(BUS)
                                        .setSource(fields.getField()));
        });
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, createAndLogError(ex, feedbacks), headers, BAD_REQUEST, request);
    }
}
```

My probem is when I throw the **MethodArgumentNotValidException** I catch it but on **ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors()** I have nothing, is all time empty but on stacktrace i can see the names of fields in error

> org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument [0] in public com.soprabanking.ibd.digitalswiftmanager.model.api.MessageApiDTO com.soprabanking.ibd.digitalswiftmanager.resource.MT103Resource.generate(com.soprabanking.ibd.digitalswiftmanager.model.api.MT103ApiDTO): [Error in object 'MT103ApiDTO': codes [FieldMustBeNullIfAnotherFieldIsIntoList.MT103ApiDTO,FieldMustBeNullIfAnotherFieldIsIntoList]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [MT103ApiDTO.,]; arguments []; default message [],**sentCharges,chargeBearer**,[Ljava.lang.String;@2bd828f4]; default message [Sent charges must be null if charge bearer code is SHA or BEN]]

I dont understand where is the problem... if someone have an answer.

Thx everyone and sorry for my bad english....

Comment: Try with `getAllErrors`, see what that comes up with.

Comment: Also, just to note: `getDefaultMessage` doesn't print the actual error. You need `MessageSource::getMessage`.

Comment: https://snipboard.io/DCBQ9R.jpg I have found fields on errors.arguments but they are on a list with some other information and i cant test with ```instanceof SpringValidatorAdapter$ResolvableAttribute``` because is private....

Comment: Your approach is not right for the task. Forget about the reflection, work with API. BTW, you do have the contraint violation in there, you just need to print it correctly.